# Parse error in custom javascript variable GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

How can i create new variable based on 2 separate current variable. The main condition is to check the existance of array or widget selector, and then return it's value:

```js
    function() {
      var array = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("div.widget-message.active.active-target a"));
      var length = array.length;
      var x = array.map(function(cn, index) {
        var nameId = cn.href.split("?")[0].split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace("-", " ");
        var urlParams = {{cjs - utility - url params}}(cn.href);
        var name = urlParams.promo_name;
        var creative = urlParams.promo_content;
        return {
          "name": "Widget - Personal - " + name,
          "id": "Widget - Personal - " + nameId + "-" + index,
          "position": "" + (index + 1) + "/" + length,
          "creative" : creative,
          "metric3": 1
        }
      });
      return {
        'ecommerce': {
          'promoView': {
            'promotions': x
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and the second one is

```js
    function() {
       var array = document.querySelector('[class="btn-new btn-fullwidth popup-trigger"]');
           return {
           'ecommerce': {
          'promoView': {
          "name": "Widget - Personal - " + array.dataset.targetId
          }
        }};
    }
```

Comment: `if (var array = ...` does not make sense for an if statement. When should the if be true, when `length > 0` I presume?

Comment: i've changed the input conditions. My final goal was to create a new variable that would check both selectors.

Comment: Okay what would the combined variable do? Contain `x` AND the other selector's name? Or just one or the other? You can only return one thing in the function. Can you just have separate data layer variables for them and use them separately in TagManager? Or what it is that you want to combine? By the way, put the three ` in a separate line so the formatting shows. I'll edit for you.

Comment: thank you Peter for your help. So, the new function should check if the first selector is valid (exists on page) and return x value, or if it is not valid, it should check the 2nd condition (2selector) and return it's value.

Comment: I have posted a possible answer for you. Keep in mind StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You should hire a developer instead of fishing for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining both functions can be done by checking `array.length` in the result of the first selector.

```js
function() {
  
  var array = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll("div.widget-message.active.active-target a"));
  var x = array.map(function(cn, index) {
    var nameId = cn.href.split("?")[0].split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace("-", " ");
    var urlParams = {{cjs - utility - url params}}(cn.href);
    return {
      "name": "Widget - Personal - " + urlParams.promo_name,
      "id": "Widget - Personal - " + nameId + "-" + index,
      "position": "" + (index + 1) + "/" + array.length,
      "creative" : urlParams.promo_content,
      "metric3": 1
    }
  });

  if (array.length > 0) {
    return {
      'ecommerce': {
        'promoView': {
          'promotions': x
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  array = document.querySelector('[class="btn-new btn-fullwidth popup-trigger"]');
  return {
    'ecommerce': {
      'promoView': {
        "name": "Widget - Personal - " + array.dataset.targetId
      }
    }
  };
}
```

See checking for `array.length > 0`. If that selector is found it will return the promotions using `x`. Otherwise the code continues and finds the other selector.

Comment: Great, glad to help! Vote up and mark it as the answer if you like 